# How to display additional fields if WTforms BooleanField checked (Flask python)?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

**models.py**

```
is_agent = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

**forms.py**

```
is_agent = BooleanField('I am an Agent')
number = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
company = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
<div class="form-check">
        {{ form.is_agent(class="form-check-input") }}
        {{ form.is_agent.label(class="form-check-label") }}
</div>
{% if form.is_agent.data == 'checked' %} # f checked, create these 2 additional fields for number/company{% endif %}
```

I am confused on how to bring all of these information together.

If the is_agent checkbox is checked by the user (it should be unchecked by default), then 2 additional fields of number/company should be displayed on the webpage.

I would appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Let this be part of your html file:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="show_additional_fields" id="show_additional_fields" onchange="toggleAdditionalFields()">
<div id="additional_fields" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    <input type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation" placeholder="Occupation">
</div>
```

Add this in your javascript:

```
function toggleAdditionalFields() {
    const showAdditionalFieldsCheckbox = document.getElementById('show_additional_fields');
    const additionalFields = document.getElementById('additional_fields');

    if (showAdditionalFieldsCheckbox.checked) {
        additionalFields.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        additionalFields.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

And it's done!